# Repeat macro until the criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I am working on a macro to do a repetitive task for me. To give you a clear view, I have prepared my initial macro (vba) code below as well as the flow chart of what it suppose to do:

Here a narrative description of the macro:

1. Check all the cells in Column K if it contains the word **"MERGED"**
2. IF the macro found the word "Merged", it will call another macro (Macro_X)
3. After calling the Macro, it will check again all the cells in Column K if it still contains the word **"MERGED"**
4. If the macro still finds the word "Merged", it will call again the Macro_X.
5. The condition will only stop until the Column K doesn't contain the word "Merged".
6. If the macro didn't find any "Merged" word in column K, it will now call the Macro_Z.

   ```
   Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
   For i = Last To 1 Step -1
       If (Cells(i, "K").Value) = "Merged" Then

           Call macro_x

       End If
   Next I
   ```

[image]

Screen shot of column K

[image]

I already have the code above but it's not working. Not sure why. Could you please help to point out what's wrong or suggest a better code?

Comment: How is it not working? are you getting error code? or it's not outputting right?

Comment: Nothing. Nothing is happening. No Output. No Error.

Comment: Check if the word Merged is typed Merged (Case sensitive). And since you did not used **Sheets()** function, make sure the sheet that you are checking is activated.

Comment: Thanks @MutjayLee, I have no issues with the sheet as well as the case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add simple Boolean variable to check if the word "MERGED" was found.

```
Dim Word_Found as Boolean

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "K").Value) = "Merged" Then
        Call macro_x

        Word_Found = True
        i = LAST

    End If
Next I

If Not(Word_Found) Then Call macro_z
```

Above code is what can be modified from your code.

Below code is written looking at your flow chart.

```
While Not (Columns("K").Find("Merged") Is Nothing)
    Call macro_x
Wend
Call macro_z
```

Comment: I've tried your code but it only do the check for 2 to 3 times only leaving the column K still having the column K  the word "merged". when I run it again, I get the error 'Run Time error 13 Type Mismatch'

Comment: Does macro_x changes values in **Column K** to "Merged"? meaning after running macro_x, do you need to check **Column K** all over again?

Comment: Yes. You may refer to the flow chart. the part where the box is named "call macro x", after doing the macro x, it will go back again to box named "Check Column K..."

Comment: I wrote another code that will do exactly what flow chart do. See if that helps

Comment: It did worked perfectly! Last question, is it possible if it will not consider the case sensitivity. I mean, the word "merged" can be written in different approaches such as "Merged", "mERGED", "MeRgEd" and so on..

Comment: FIND function is not case sensitive, so it will work

Answer (score 1):

You can call your initial macro at the end of your Macro_X.
for the initial macro:

```
Sub checker()
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To Last Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "K").Value) = "Merged" Then

        Call macro_x

    End If
Next I
Call macro_z
End Sub
```

for macro_x:

```
Sub macro_x()
'DO SOMETHING HERE

Call checker
End Sub
```

EDIT:

```
For i = 1 To Last Step -1
```

Comment: Thanks @9i2 for your answer. unfortunately, it didn't worked as well. There is no error but it's calling the macro_z without doing the sub_checker which leaves the criteria or condition unsatisfied.

Comment: In Addition to my edited answer. if your cell contain characters other than "Merged" .. you may use " * Merged * "

Answer (score 1):

First thing I see is "merged" in your cell doesn't start with capital letter but in your code does.

So please change to this.

```
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "K").Value) = "merged" Then

        Call macro_x

    End If
Next I
```